# How to set a marker at the position of googles places or points of interest

Tags: android, json, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I would like to set a marker at a the locations of certain types of places in google maps...not one specific place, rather all places that come up as "business" or "schools", etc.

I can't figure out how to customize google's default points of interest icons, so I figured I would just create a custom marker and set it at those locations, while hiding the default location icons using JSON:

```
{
"featureType": "poi.business",
"elementType": "labels.icon",
"stylers": [
  {
    "visibility": "off"
  }
 ]
}
```

but I'm not sure how to show a marker at all "business" locations.

Edit:

Is there a way to place a marker at specific points of interest?

Comment: do you have latitude and longitude of your locations?  for add a marker or group of marks, you need lat and lang  for each location

Comment: I'm looking to add them to the existing points of interest relative to any user's location.  Maybe there's a Nike store near you...I wouldn't know that position, but Google's "places" would put a generic icon representing a business.  So I'd like to know how to use the location of "businesses" and add a marker there instead of lat/lng position.

Comment: i dont have prices info about you question, but i found two link in google apies one for finding places and another for get detail of a place: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search     https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details    probably you must find places that you want, and then you must add them on your map one by one with your own mark

Comment: Thanks...I might be able to use the search function to locate the types of places I want to place a marker.  I'll try that